# Importing a class property from one file to another in python

Tags: python

So I was wondering how to import some code from one file to another. I have a player class in one of my files, as seen below

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos, surface, create_jump_particles, direction):
```

One of the properties is `direction`, as shown here.

```
self.direction = pygame.math.Vector2(0, 0)
```

I have another file called Settings, and I am trying to import the Player class (specifically the direction attribute) to it.

Can someone tell me why this code doesn't work?

```
from player import Player

if Player.direction.x <= 0:
    [...]
```

Here is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\PlatformerGame.py", line 4, in <module>
    from Settings import *
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\Settings.py", line 4, in <module>
    if Player.direction.x <= 0:
AttributeError: type object 'Player' has no attribute 'direction'
```

I don't know if this causes any issues, by I also do import something from settings to player.

Answer (score 0):

You use self when you create an instance of a class. That instance is basically what we refer to as `self`. However, here you do not seem to be creating any instance.

You can create a `player` instance:

```py
player = Player(pos, surface, create_jump_particles, direction) # Fill in these fields.
if player.direction.x < 0:
...
```